# Diode. Send more than 1 action in circuit

Tags: scala, frontend, scala.js, diode

Colleagues, I cant make `diode`, to send itself more than one action from another action. here the example from `App circuit`:

```
val handler = new ActionHandler(myZoomedState) {
    override def handle = {
      case action => effectOnly(Effect(someFuture map {_ =>
        someAction  //This action doesn't perform 
        someOtherAction  //This one does
      }))

      case someAction => ???
      case someOtherAction => ???
    }
}
```

How can chain I actions? Something like `>>` whith `callbacks`:
`someCallback >> someOtherCallback`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to create another action, combining this two actions. And I still can handle `Future` error. Looks like this:

```
case object DoSmthStuff
...

val handler = new ActionHandler(myZoomedState) {
    override def handle = {
      case action => effectOnly(Effect(
          someFuture map { _ => DoSmthStuff } recover { ... }
      ))

      case DoSmthStuff = effectOnly(
          Effect.action(someAction) >> Effect.action(someOtherAction)
      )

      case someAction => ???
      case someOtherAction => ???
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oleg, your questions is quite not clear. If your handlers of `someAction` and `someOtherAction` are actually effect-only as implementation of your `case action` suggests, you can move them into a named methods and combine them using [`<<` or `>>` or `+`](https://diode.suzaku.io/usage/Effects.html#combining-effects). If this is not what you want, you should elaborate your problem in more details.

Comment: They are not effects, they are actions. My solution is to create another action, combining this actions.

Comment: @Oleg, you can freely combine effects exactly because they are just effects. For state-changing actions you should provide more details on what exactly those actions do and what combined semantics you expect to get. I don't think one can answer your question in its current generic form. I suspect that the solution you provided in your answer will not work correctly in all cases especially since you use potentially concurrent `+`.

Comment: Sure, but I can't combine effects inside another effect. So, in my question, I can't just put `someAction` and `someOtherAction` into `Effect.action()`.

Comment: `someFuture` is the rest request to delete item. If it was succeed, I want to perform 2 actions. First one is to update my state by `updated(value.copy( ... ))`. Second one - to recalculate my `Pot` data by sending another rest request.